# Advanced custom fields - If/ while field issue

Tags: wordpress

The way I am trying to set this up is that if a link has not been chosen then only the image will be displayed, but if a link is chosen as well as an image then I want the link to be wrapped around the image, here is an example of what I have at the moment:

```
<?php if(get_field('block_repeater')): ?>
     <ul>

         <?php while(has_sub_field('block_repeater')): ?>
         <li>
            <!-- problem -->
             <?php if( get_sub_field('block_link') ): ?>

                 <?php while(has_sub_field('block_image')): ?>
                    <a class="img" href="<?php the_sub_field('block_link'); ?>">
                         <img src="<?php the_sub_field('block_image'); ?>" alt="" />
                         <span class="square-arrow"></span>
                     </a>
                 <?php endwhile; ?>

             <?php endif; ?>
            <!--//problem -->

             <?php if( get_sub_field('block_image') ): ?>
                 <img src="<?php the_sub_field('block_image'); ?>" alt="" />
             <?php endif; ?>
         </li>
         <?php endwhile; ?>

     </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The does not seem to be working correctly though as its rendering out about a hundred of these:

```
<a class="img" href="">
<img alt="" src="">
<span class="square-arrow"></span>
</a>
```

Don't suppose anyone knows what I have done wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are doing a loop and keeping that `html` block between `while` loop so this block is being printed until the loop ends.

```
<?php while(has_sub_field('block_image')): ?>
    <!--
        This part will be printed as long as 
        has_sub_field('block_image') returns true
    -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

If you want to print out that part only once, then remove the loop, just comment out these lines, like

```
<?php //while(has_sub_field('block_image')): ?>
    <!-- keep everything here as it is -->
<?php //endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ahh I see, but if I comment this out and there isn't an image then there will just be an empty image tag on the page

Comment: You can check using `<?php if( get_sub_field('block_image') ): ?>`.